# Can geoserver oracle spatial ds recognize public synonyms

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to find out if geoserver can view tables referenced by a public synonym in oracle spatial. We get regular updates to our data and save them in the db as [type]_[date] so we'd like to create a synonym like [type] that we can update when new data comes in so that geoserver doesn't constantly need a new data_dir release for new data updates.

Comment: have you tried it? what happens? most of the core GeoServer team only boot an instance with Oracle on when people pay us to :-)

Comment: If public synonym has an entry in sdo_geom_metadata it should work just like tables and views. You can also look your data through a view or by making a SQL query layer into GeoServer.

Answer (score 1):

Public synonyms can be published as layers, although the easiest way (as @user30184 suggested) is using GeoServer's [SQL Views](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html).  I've done this successfully with an SQL View, also using the SQL View Parameters feature to trigger a [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/csql.htm#CCREF0104) operator.

There's a slight problem with publishing public synonyms directly because, although they'll appear in the list of resources available if you set up a Store with the current user's schema, GeoServer will by default look at the MDSYS.USER_SDO* and MDSYS.ALL_SDO* views when using looking for geometry metadata entries, and it's not possible to create entries for objects owned by *public* (e.g. public synonyms) that appear in those views.  Inserting entries directly into the SDO_GEOM_METADATA_TABLE is not recommended, so I wouldn't do it.  Another option would be to manually create the Geometry metadata table, as described in GeoServer's documentation.

Maybe you could consider using a private synonyms, which avoids the problem described above because the owner of the object is the current user.  I also understand that public synonyms should be avoided if possible.

Hope that helps